# Contacts are not being pushed to email activity after the wait activity, what can be possible issue. I can still see contacts in wait activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have created a Journey, with decision split deciding If the contacts already registered should move to exit, If they are new then They will wait for a min after the automation triggering contacts to Journey and later once the contacts are pushed to decision split, they should either go to exit or wait activity following email activity. Contacts can be seen as new and shows up in wait activity however not proceeding further to email activity. What can be the possible issue here?

---

Thank you for looking into this .. I have no goal setting or exit criteria. I was able to figure it out that the Journey was running on file drop automation where the file dropped at US timezone at 1pm and at the same time there was a 1 minute wait duration used when contacts entered wait activity it was already 1pm and 1 minute. When I had a closer look at the wait activity the earlier vendor has check marked option "Extend wait duration until specific time" 1pm hence the emails were sent on the next day at 1 pm. This issue is resolved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up exit criteria or goal criteria? These are evaluated each time a contact leaves the wait step. Hence if this person matches the exit criteria, we will not see him or her progress to the email activity, but will exit the journey instead. You can check the details in the Journey Health feature of your journey, where you can look up contact key of an individual who did not enter the email activity as expected.

You can see an example of journey health below:

[image]